# Помогите пожалуйста определить типы выделенных предложений

Tags: синтаксис

1) Она хотела закатить ему сцену ревности, но потом отказалась от этой мысли: **а вдруг он именно на это и рассчитывал**.

(После двоеточия объясняется причина, почему она отказалась от этой мысли, или это простое предложение?)

2) И **если вначале он был готов бороться за ее любовь**, то теперь, наоборот, он хотел отпустить ее на все четыре стороны.

(не пойму, временное или условное... хотя вроде и какое-то сопоставление в предложении чувствуется)

3) Меня в дрожь бросало от одной мысли, **что весь кошмар снова повторится**.

(склоняюсь к определительному, но не уверена, как правильно ставить вопрос "от какой мысли?" или "от чего бросало в дрожь?")

4) Он решил ждать, пока она сама не согласится поговорить с ним, **хотя бы один краткий миг**.  (уступительный оборот?)

5) Не прошло и года, **как он попросил меня выйти за него замуж**. (придаточное времени?)

6) Больной сам пришел показаться в больницу, **так что, похоже, не успел никого заразить**. (придаточное следствия?)

7) Он попытался ввести обязательное обучение для бедняков – **как самим построить уборную**.

Answer (score 2):

1) Верно, БСП, 2 часть раскрывает причину того, о чём говорится в 1.

2) И если вначале он был готов бороться за ее любовь, то теперь, наоборот, он хотел отпустить ее на все четыре стороны.- Сложное сопоставительное предложение: сопоставляются 2 факта, один из которых более важный.

3) Меня в дрожь бросало от одной мысли(о чём? какой?), что весь кошмар снова повторится.-Согласна с Верой, "что" здесь союз, придаточное относится к сущ. со значением мысли, можно подставить О ТОМ, это изъяснительное с дополнительным значением определительного, а определительным было бы, если б  ЧТО было союзным словом.

4) Он решил ждать, пока она сама не согласится поговорить с ним, хотя бы один краткий миг. -присоединительная конструкция, обстоятельство времени.

5) Не прошло и года(с каких пор?), как он попросил меня выйти за него замуж. - придаточное времени.

6) Больной сам пришел показаться в больницу, так что, похоже, не успел никого заразить. -придаточное следствия

7) Он попытался ввести обязательное обучение для бедняков – как самим построить уборную.-бессоюзное сложное с присоединительными отношениями, можно во 2 части подставить ЭТО.

Comment: Про #1: Что означает "Б" в "БСП"?  И как это соответствует наличию "а" в предложении?

Comment: "Меня в дрожь бросало от одной мысли(какой?), что весь кошмар снова повторится.-определительное". Разве в определительном предложении может быть союз ЧТО?

Comment: А почему нет? «Компьютер, что ты купил, сломан».

Comment: Здесь "что" - союзное слово, а не союз.

Comment: В таком случае какую роль в предложении здесь играет это *ЧТО*?

Comment: В предложении опущены слова "о том": "... от одной мысли [о том], что...", так что "что" - подчинительный союз.

Comment: Виктор, БСП-бессоюзное сложное предложение, это всем известное условное обозначение. "А" здесь никак не союз, он ничего не противопоставляет, это частица, которая не мешает бессоюзной связи.

Answer (score 2):

2) И если вначале он был готов бороться за ее любовь, то теперь, наоборот, он хотел отпустить ее на все четыре стороны.

СПП с придаточным сопоставительным, сопоставительный союз ЕСЛИ...ТО, значение несоответствия выражено с помощью специальной сопоставительной лексики: вначале - теперь.

Сопоставительное значение для условно-следственного союза ЕСЛИ...ТО вторично, оно развивается только в определенном контексте.